# Sum of column depending on values of another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was wondering how can I make a query that outputs the sum of a column "B" based on the values of column "A".

Example table:

```
A B
1 2
1 6
2 3
3 1
2 9
3 7
```

Desired query output:

```
A B
1 8
2 12
3 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty basic SQL that any tutorial would cover. Use the `sum` aggregate function together with `group by`. The `group by` determines the groups that you apply the `sum` function over.

```
select a, sum(b) as sum_of_b from your_table group by a
```

Comment: OK, got it to work. How about a more complicated one. Can I do this twice in one query, referring to 2 different tables.

Comment: @SpetsnazBeaver - For the complicated one first you need to give it a try then if you are facing any problem in finding the solution come back here